# Why was my answer deleted, after fixing it exactly as the mod said to do?

Tags: discussion, deleted-answers

https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/44955/6893

I submitted an answer, one mod deleted it, saying it didn't answer the question.

I then edited the answer, including sources which directly answered the question.

I then clicked undelete, but nothing happened.

So, I resubmitted the answer.

Why was it deleted again?  I did exactly what the first mod wanted me to do.

Answer (score 5):

After editing sufficiently to allow for undeletion, you should click "undelete" if possible, flag the post for moderator attention to undelete, and/or raise the issue here or in chat. Reposting the same answer (even if modified) is, besides being a waste of screen 'real estate', possibly posting again something that should still not be there.

Comment: @Jake To be honest I didn't notice that the previous answer had been edited and just saw that the two were identical, so I apologize. That said, msh210's answer here seems to be correct IMO. +1

Comment: I suspect (but haven't created a second account to test with) that Jake wasn't able to undelete because it was deleted by a moderator.  The interface probably did not give the most helpful of error messages; sorry about that, Jake.  Any time you want to draw moderators' attention to something, you should be able to flag it.  Then choose "other" to write a custom message and explain what's going on.  Thanks.